# Why is tf_broadcast_publisher creating future tfs

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I've a question about publishing tfs that are valid in the future.
https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/noetic-devel/tf/src/static_transform_publisher.cpp#L79

I found this also in robot_state_publisher with use_static_tf false.
https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/blob/noetic-devel/src/robot_state_publisher.cpp#L129

I configured move_base to control not directly on base link but on a point a bit shifted to the center which shows a good result in 'smoothing' the movements a bit.

Before trying with tf_broadcast_publisher I published the tf from base_link to control_link myself but thought it might make sense to remove that and just use the tf_broadcast_publisher I'm running it with

```
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="control_link_broadcaster" args="-0.3 0 0 0 0 0 base_link control_link 100"/>
```

The tf looks then like that (its from the simulation with gazebo not live on the robot)

[image: tf]

With a tf from base_link to control_link in the future. When running the navigation now trying to transform the path it throws errors with the "Lookup would require extrapolation into the future" message.

I mean I'm fine publishing that tf myself without that + sleeper thing but I'm interested in the rational behind that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374253/why-is-tf_broadcast_publisher-creating-future-tfs/) by [Webadone](https://answers.ros.org/users/72129/webadone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2021-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The use of future dating for static and approximately static transforms is a tool used to avoid latency prior to the addition of truely static transforms in tf2.

There's more info in the [tf/FAQ](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/FAQ)

I'd recommend moving to a [tf2 static transform](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2?distro=noetic#Adding_static_transform_support) instead which will be more robust and lower overhead.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Webadone](https://answers.ros.org/users/72129/webadone/) on 2021-03-19**:
Understood, thanks a lot for your quick reply!